# Magento: New Payment Method Not Show in Checkout

Tags: magento, methods, payment, checkout

I'm using the Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

I've read the official guide for create new Payment Methods:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

in directory `app/etc/modules` i've created this xml file `MyName_MyModule`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>  
<modules>  
    <MyName_MyModule>  
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>  
    </MyName_MyModule>  
</modules>
```

In `app/code/local` i've created this folders `MyName/MyModule`
and: `MyName/MyModule/etc` `MyName/MyModule/Model`

inside `MyName/MyModule/etc` there is(config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyName_MyModule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyName_MyModule>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyName_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>MyName_MyModule</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
        <mymodule_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_write>
        <mymodule_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_read>
    </resources>     
</global>
```

and system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <payment>
        <groups>
            <mymodule translate="label" module="payment">
                <label>My Module</label>
                <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <active translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </active>
                    <title translate="label">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </title>
                </fields>
            </mymodule>
        </groups>
    </payment>
</sections>
```

The problem is:

I see the payment method in the panel administration
also i see it in system / advanced

when i enable the payment method and try to buy something,
i can't see it in Payment Information!

I see only 2 radio buttons:
Check / Money order
Credit Card (saved)

Cache cleared manually, and disabled from administration panel.

Added Default:

```
        <!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
    <default>
        <!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
        <payment>
            <!-- 'newmodule' configuration group (fieldset) -->
            <mymodule>
                <!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
                <active>1</active>
                <!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->
                <model>mymodule/paymentMethod</model>
                <!-- order status for new orders paid by this payment method -->
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <!-- default title for payment checkout page and order view page -->
                <title>My Module</title>

                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </mymodule>
        </payment>
    </default>
```

Still doesn't work!

Comment: added default... not work!

Comment: So, did anything work for you? If yes, can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add in your config xml

```
 <default>
<!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
        <payment>
<!-- 'newmodule' configuration group (fieldset) -->
            <newmodule>
<!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
                <active>0</active>
<!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->
                <model>newmodule/paymentMethod</model>
<!-- order status for new orders paid by this payment method -->
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
<!-- default title for payment checkout page and order view page -->
                <title>Credit Card (Authorize.net)</title>

                <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI</cctypes>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </newmodule>
         </payment>
    </default>
```

without this you can not see payment option at payment page.

hope this will sure solve your issue.

Comment: @Gi Gu,i am sure my answer is sure help you and it would be glad for me if you will acept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful. I think your config.xml file has missed some configurations. Refer this link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/